# Wedge product of maps: functorial vs. exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$. If $\varphi, \psi \in \hom(V,W)$, there are at least two interpretations of the symbol $\varphi \wedge \psi$:

1. It is the wedge product in the exterior algebra of the vector space $\hom(V,W)$.
2. It
       is the image of $\varphi, \psi$ under the functor $\bigwedge$, i.e.
       a map $V \wedge V \to W \wedge W$. (**Edit:** Mariano has pointed out to me that this does not make sense in general)

**First Question:** I gather that these two interpretations have nothing to do with each other? This is kind of confusing when for instance $W=\mathbb{F}$, and we have $\varphi \wedge \psi$ as an element of $(V^* \wedge V^*)$, but under the second interpretation $\varphi \wedge \psi = 0$, because $\mathbb{F} \wedge \mathbb{F} = 0$. (**Edit:** this question does not make sense, as Mariano points out.)

**Second Question:** Again in the special case $W=\mathbb{F}$, we can understand the action of $\varphi_1 \wedge \dotsb \wedge \varphi_k$ by taking an isomorphism $\bigwedge^k(V^*)  \xrightarrow{\alpha} (\bigwedge^k(V))^*$ given by $\alpha(\varphi_1 \wedge \dotsb \wedge \varphi_n)(v_1 \wedge \dotsb \wedge v_n) = \det(\varphi_i(v_j))$. As far as I can tell, this correspondence is mostly arbitrary. Is this correct?

**Third Question:** When $W \neq \mathbb{F}$, how can I understand the operation of $\varphi_1 \wedge \dotsb \wedge \varphi_k$ on $\bigwedge^k(V)$? Would we then need some correspondence $\bigwedge^k(V^* \otimes W) \to (\bigwedge^k(V \otimes W^*))^*$?

Comment: Your bullet point $2$ does not make sense. What you *can* do is to take a map $f:V\to W$ and induce from it a map $f^{\wedge k}:\Lambda^kV\to\Lambda^kW$. But if $f$ and $g$ are two maps $V\to W$, there is no such thing as $f\wedge g:V\wedge V\to W\wedge W$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez OK. But why not? $(v_1, v_2) \mapsto f(v_1) \wedge g(v_2)$ is surely multilinear.

Comment: That is not multilinear: it is not even well defined! $v_1\wedge v_2$ is the same thing as $(-v_2)\wedge v_1$, yet there is no reason for $f(v_1)\wedge g(v_2)$ to be the same thing as $f(-v_2)\wedge g(v_1)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks. Any ideas for the other two questions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "this correspondence is mostly arbitrary"?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I mean that there's no natural action of $\bigwedge^k(V^*)$ on $\bigwedge^k(V)$, just the fact that $\bigwedge^K(V^*)$ and $(\bigwedge^k(V))^*$ have the same dimension, so we pick an isomorphism which is convenient to us.

Comment: This question was answered better here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377279/identification-between-wedge-product-and-its-dual

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez is incorrect. We can define the wedge product $f\wedge g:V\wedge V\to W\wedge W$ by $$(f\wedge g)(v_1\wedge v_2)=f(v_1)\wedge g(v_2)+g(v_1)\wedge f(v_2).$$ This is commutative, $f\wedge g=g\wedge f$. And similarly we can define $f\wedge g\wedge h$ as a sum of $3!$ terms, etc.